# Hacer con un bucle for XYSeries JFreeChart

Tags: java

me encuentro en la siguiente situación. Tengo un arraylist de arraylist del cual quiero sacar una gráfica con JFreeChart. Tengo ya creada una serie, pero necesito que se me creen de forma automática según las posiciones del arraylist, serie2,serie3...

Para generar una sola tengo el siguiente código:

```
final XYSeries serie1 = new XYSeries("");
            num.add(new ArrayList<Double>());
            for(int i=1;i<grafica.size();i++){ 
                    for(int j=1;j<grafica.get(i).size();j++){  
                        aux = Double.parseDouble(grafica.get(i).get(j));
                        numTime=Double.parseDouble(grafica.get(0).get(j));
                                serie1.add( numTime, aux);
                                 }
```

*Gráfica es el arraylist.

Muchas gracias.